# Android Studio 3.2.1 freezes all the time

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, jetbrains-ide

Since I updated my Android Studio from 3.1.4 to 3.2.1, it freezes all the time and it is really frustrating. Same problem for my colleagues. Does anyone face the same problem? Is there a way to fix it? thanks

Comment: Same issue. No solution. It actually worked pretty well for a while till I started debugging on a local device. I suspect it has something to do with that, but with Google, who knows.

Comment: having the same issues.

Comment: What is the Solution ?

Comment: I am using now Android studio 3.3, I don't have the problem anymore. PS: this is my VM config: -Xms512m
-Xmx4g
-XX:MaxPermSize=700m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50